# realtime teechart using javascript getting error after hit the api 2nd time

Tags: javascript, teechart

i had created a real-time using teechart html5 javascript. every thing works fine for a first time . But when the api hit 2nd time and push data in array i got an error i.e "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
Any type of help is appreciated . Thanks in advance
below is my cde:

```
function loaddata(d_s,d_l){
if(s==0) {
      resizeCanvas();
}
    abc = [];
    customData = [];
console.log("the start and end values are", d_s, d_l);
$.getJSON('http://dgmv1lmgqmyfc.cloudfront.net/eeg/api/?from='+d_s+'&to='+d_l , function(json) {
    var data = $.makeArray(json) ;
    for (var i =0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
        customData.push([
                          data[i].c1,
                          data[i].c2,
                          data[i].c3,
                          data[i].c4,
                          data[i].c5,
                          data[i].c6,
                          data[i].c7,
                          data[i].c8,
                          data[i].c9,
                          data[i].c10,
                          data[i].c11,
                          data[i].c12,
                          data[i].c13,
                          data[i].c14,
                          data[i].c15,
                          data[i].c16,
                          data[i].c17,
                          data[i].c18,
                          data[i].c19,
                          data[i].id 
                        ]);
      }
    abc = customData;
datasize = abc.length;
num = abc[0].length - 1;

for(var i=0; i<datasize; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j<num; j++)
    {   
        abc[i][j]=abc[i][j]+j*margin;
    }
}
draw();
});

this.d_start = this.d_start + this.d_length + 1 ;
this.d_length = this.d_length + 2476 ;
}
```

function draw() {

```
if (s == 0)
{
Chart1=new Tee.Chart('canvas');

addSeries(1);

Chart1.panel.transparent=true;
Chart1.walls.back.visible=false;    
Chart1.legend.visible=false;

Chart1.axes.left.title.text='Data';
Chart1.title.text='';
}

if(on == 0)
      Chart1.draw();
if(on == 1)
      requestAnimFrame(newData, Chart1, 1);

function newData() {
iCounter++ ;
    if(on == 0) return;
      for(var t=0; t < num; t++){ // loop run 19 times
        var d=Chart1.getSeries(t).data.values;
        var x=Chart1.getSeries(t).data.x;
        var l=d.length;
        var e = document.getElementById('sel_shift');
    //console.log("asdsadsad",x);
    //exit;
        nrshift = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    for (v=0; v<nrshift; v++){ // loop run 20 time is 20 selected from dropdown

        if((x[l-1]+v)>=d_start){break;} /////////

        if(x[l-1]>=d_length){
        var cn = x[l-1];
        for(;cn > d_length-1;){
          cn = cn - d_length;
        }

        d[l]= abc[cn][t];
        if(cn<1){
          d[l]=d[l-1];
        }

        }else{
        d[l]= abc[x[l-1]+v][t];
        //console.log(abc[x[l-1]+v][t]);
        }

        x[l]= x[l-1]+1;
        d.shift();
        x.shift();
    }
    //console.log("the updated countrer is", iCounter);
      }

    Chart1.draw();
      if((x[l-1])>=d_start){
    //this.d_start = this.d_start + this.d_length ;
    loaddata(d_start,d_length);
      }else{
          requestAnimFrame(newData,Chart1,1);
      }
}
```

} //draw method closed here

Comment: In which line of code do you get the error?

Comment: Thanks David Berneda for your reply . i'm getting error in this line.  d[l]= abc[x[l-1]+v][t]; (in this line)

Comment: Its hard to determine the exact reason of the exception without reproducing the project, but looks like the d.shift or x.shift calls are resizing the array until gets empty.